# Toshi o kattara, unten shimasen

Tags: english-to-japanese

What's the translation of this sentence? Google doesn't work, is there a better alternativ

Answer (score 2):

> Toshi o kattara, unten shimasen

「都市｛とし｝を買｛か｝ったら、運転｛うんてん｝しません」？？？
「年｛とし｝を買｛か｝ったら、運転｛うんてん｝しません」？？？

There may be typo in the sentence.

1. > Toshi o kuttara, unten shimasen - 
   >   「年｛とし｝を食｛く｝ったら、運転｛うんてん｝しません」
2. > Toshi o tottara, unten shimasen - 
   >   「年｛とし｝を取｛と｝ったら、運転｛うんてん｝しません」

Both sentences mean the same as:
If I age, I'll not drive a car.

Comment: If it wasn't a typo, could it mean "If I bought a town, I wouldn't be managing it?" Anyway, this question is really low quality...

Comment: @siikamiika >"If I bought a town, I wouldn't be managing it?" As an interesting story you could lease the right of management of the town, but isn't it an unrealistic story, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's a strange thing to say, but I was just wondering if 運転する could word that way. Apparently yes?

Comment: @sikamiika > Apparently yes?   Yes, it is  just like the word usage of 運転 in 「運転資金」 which means "operating fund."